# identifying unknown script from artefact

Tags: avestan

A friend found these artefacts for sale in Afghanistan, was wondering what the script is? Maybe Avestan?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before this item gets deleted: It is a crude forgery, a poor imitation of Avestan script. Some of the world's leading specialists have commented on it on my facebook page. Please contact me privately for the link. fcd23@cam.ac.uk